# How to replace / substitute a jQuery target

Tags: jquery

I am trying to replace/substitute one of the jQuery targets below (not the HTML element), depending on which language is selected by the user.

For example, if user chooses English as language, I want to remove `#English` target, but keep the others (i.e. `#Spanish, #German`).

How can I do this?

```
 $( "#English, #Spanish, #German").click function { blah, blah, blah };
```

Comment: show us your html.. where do you want to substitue?

Comment: do you want to remove the click handler once it is clicked

Comment: @Arun P Johny, no everything stays the same, except `#English` is removed.

Comment: Your question should be rephrased with `HTML`, it's confusing.

Comment: Are you wanting the the element removed? just add $(this).remove() to your click handler

Comment: Did you mean `click` by `choses` and want to let one language be clicked only once ? also, this is not a good way to have `$(#eng, #others)` for 71 `elements`, instead use a `class`.

Comment: Hi guys, I updated the question, as I agree it was confusing.  I only want to remove `#English` TARGET in jQuery.  I want to keep all of the HTML elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to just check in the handler to see whether it's the chosen language.

```
var chosen_language = 'English'; // This can be updated by some other code

$("#English, #Spanish, #German").click(function() {
    if (this.id != chosen_language) {
        blah blah blah;
    }
});
```

Comment: He wants to remove the target, not the element I think. By removing a target I think he asks to remove that ID from the selector.

Comment: @Barmar, I would like to remove only the `#English` target.  Is this possible with your solution above?

Comment: He means that if english is chosen. Then the function should update to `$( "#Spanish, #German").click function { blah, blah, blah };`

Comment: @Barmar, this is making good sense to me......I will take a look at yours first and see if it works.  I will need a few hours....thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to trigger the handler for an element only once, in that case use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$( "#English, #Spanish, #German").one('click', function(){
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Unbind the id click event

```
$("#English, #Spanish, #German").click( function(){

    $(this).unbind('click');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass who was selected to a variable and then use it as a filter to the main target:

```
var filter = $('#english');
$('#german, #english, #spanish').not(filter).on('click',function(){ //...
```

Also, avoid using `.click()`, use `.on()` instead (if you are not using older jQuery versions).

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3V4k2/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think it's a proper/good way to bind `event handler` using `ID`s for `71` elements (you mentioned in your question) like

```
$( "#English, #Spanish, #German").click(...);
```

Instead, you can use a `class` for all of your elements like this

```
<a class='language' id="English" href="whatever">English</a>
<a class='language' id="Spanish" href="whatever">Spanish</a>
<a class='language' id="German" href="whatever">German</a>
```

In this case you don't need individual `ID`s but if you need for some other reason then you may keep an unique `ID` for each elements. Now to bind a `click` handler for all the `link`s that has the class `language`, you may use something like this

```
$(".language").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do whatever you want to do then update the click handler
    alert($(this).text() + ' is selected!');

    // Then update the click handler instead of removing it because
    // if you remove the click handler then next time yopu click the
    // link, it'll do it's default behavior, will be navigated away
    $(this).off('click').on('click', function(){ return false; });
});
```

Also, you can use a namespace for the `click` handler like

```
$(".language").on('click.langualeSelection', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do it once
    alert($(this).text() + ' is selected!');

    // remove only this handler, other handler will prevent default
    // behavior but if there is no other handler, then update it like
    // previous example given above to stop loading the linked page
    $(this).off('click.langualeSelection');
});
```

Another handler

```
$(".language").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Another click handler for language class');
});
```

Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/s69gb/2/) for one click handler and [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/s69gb/5/) for more than one handlers but one handler will be `off` after it fired once.